# Metaflow - AWS batch task fails after deleting conda folder from S3

Tags: conda, aws-batch, netflix-metaflow

I am using [Metaflow](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow) on AWS in batch mode. I deleted the conda folder from s3. Now when I try to run a batch task, it fails in the bootstrapping environment step.

Apparently `metaflow.plugins.conda.batch_bootstrap` tries to download conda packages using the `cache_urls` associated with the environment id from the conda.dependencies file. The issue is described in some more detail [here](https://gitter.im/metaflow_org/community?at=5e1791ba3679536f963982e6).

How can I fix this problem so that I can run a metaflow batch task again?

Comment: I realized that rebooting solves this issue. Would be much better though if this problem was handled by Metaflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kanimbla metaflow maintains a manifest folder `.metaflow` either in the same directory as your flow or in one of the parent directories. Deleting it resets your flow's dependencies.